# MySQL replace into and get last insert ID

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, will a REPLACE INTO query work with the LAST_INSERT_ID function?

Essentially, I have to insert into one table, only where it doesn't exist, but then either way insert into the second table with a foreign key constraint of the first table.

So ie.

```
REPLACE INTO TABLE1(NAME) VALUES('unique');
SET @table1_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO TABLE2(TABLE1_ID, VALUE) VALUES(@table1_id, 'Test Value');
```

Will that function as intended on both an insert and an update?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `REPLACE INTO` query affects the result of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function.

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) states:

> `REPLACE` works **exactly** like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

That means if `INSERT` affects `LAST_INSERT_ID()` then `REPLACE` should do it too.

I have tested it with MySQL 8.